# How do I get grep working in a function while assigned to a new variable?

Tags: shell, scripting

Trying to write a script that takes a domain name, does a whois, writes it to a variable, then runs a bunch of grep's on it.

So the first part works, the variable gets the whois text and stores it in another variable. The problem is what I've written to parse that is not working.

```
# Assigns the passed variable $1 to domain.
domain=$1

rawWhois=`whois -H $domain`

# Runs several whois queries and assigns the results to variables.
function whoisTool() {
    whoisNS=`echo $rawWhois | grep -m 2 'Name Server'`
}
```

The result should look something like:

```
Name Server: NS1.BLUEHOST.COM
Name Server: NS2.BLUEHOST.COM
```

Comment: Shellcheck produces [5 findings for your code](https://pastebin.com/dE8aiMKL). You should clear them before continuing.

Comment: Hey. What is Shellcheck? I'm new to all this. Thanks. Edit: I found it, thanks.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: You never call `whoisTool`.

Comment: So I didn't paste all of the code, most of those errors are because of that, but good news, following the tips from ShellCheck, the code now works. I used $() instead of the ``, and put the variables in double quotes. That got me the exact result I was looking for. So it mentions the backticks are depreciated, so I should use $() from now on I guess. Anyway thanks for recommending a tool to check my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected result, I guess you may consider using `sed` too :

```
whois -H "$1" | sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*Name Server/{N;s/[[:blank:]]*Name/Name/gp;q}'
```

Comment: Eventually I want to learn more about AWK and SED, I'm at the beginning stages of learning right now.